# xubuntu/xfce4 package to hold to prevent breakage by updates

Tags: apt, xubuntu, package-management, xfce

I've painfully set up my xubuntu desktop to look exactly how I want it to look. I have previously experienced a well built setup crumble due to unfortunate updates. Though I would like to keep getting updates for applications, linux headers, drivers etc, I would like to keep the desktop itself untouched.

What is the complete list of packages I need to hold to keep my desktop environment from changing unknowingly?

Here is my current system:
Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) with xubuntu installed later and Unity removed
Xfce ver. 4.10

I want to hold packages using `apt-mark hold <package-name>`